# Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I try to modify existing example - [Tonr2 and Sparklr2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples).
Also I viewed this tutorial based on Spring Boot [Spring Boot OAuth2](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v). I try to build application like in Tonr2 example but without first login (on tonr2). I just need one Authentication on Sparklr2 side. I do this:

```
@Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails sparklr() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        details.setId("sparklr/tonr");
        details.setClientId("tonr");
        details.setTokenName("oauth_token");
        details.setClientSecret("secret");
        details.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        details.setUserAuthorizationUri(userAuthorizationUri);
        details.setScope(Arrays.asList("openid"));
        details.setGrantType("client_credentials");
        details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.none);
        details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.none);
        return details;
    }
```

But I have `Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)` . I checked [this question](http://Authentication%20is%20required%20to%20obtain%20an%20access%20token%20(anonymous%20not%20allowed)). Of course, my user is anonymous - I want to login on Sparklr2. Also, I tried different combinations of settings of this bean, but nothing good. How to fix it? How to make it work as I want?

Answer (score 2):

Almost two years late for the post.

The exception is thrown from [AccessTokenProviderChain](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/AccessTokenProviderChain.java#L91)

```
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            if (!resource.isClientOnly()) {
                throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                    "Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)");
            }
        }
```

You either

- Use `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails` in your `OAuth2RestTemplate`, or
- Authenticate the user before using `AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails` to access external resources

In fact, in the `tonr2 and sparklr2` example (I personally find the name very confusing), to access resources on `sparklr2`, a user has to first authenticate on `tonr2`. As seen in [oauth2/tonr](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/tonr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/config/SecurityConfig.java#L16):

```
@Override

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("marissa").password("wombat").roles("USER").and().withUser("sam")
            .password("kangaroo").roles("USER");
}
```

If your user is anonymous, you might want to check for [Single Sign On](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-single-sign-on).

For whoever just want to quickly try out Oauth2 integration, add basic auth to your application:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.security.user.password=password
spring.security.user.name=user
```

Don't forget to add `spring-boot-starter-security` to your project.

e.g. In gradle:     `compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'`

Or you can also disable `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` from creating by:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.anonymous().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post...

The exception indeed is thrown form AccessTokenProviderChain but it happens when spring security filters invoking if incorrect order.  Make sure that your OpenIdAuthenticationFilter is invoking after OAuth2ClientContextFilter.